# Using multiple io_context in one process lead to timeout

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a function that run process by calling `boost::process::child` definition with `io_context`. right after the child creation, I call `io_context.run_for(timeout)` and when it finishes I know that either timeout have passed or process terminate succesfully.

The process stdout goes to variable from type `std::future<std::string>` so I check if the data is ready right after the io_context finished running.

The first calls goes smooth. However, after several successful attempts, I get the next calls some weird behavior, so that the io_context.run_for finish promptly with timeout value (although the timeout surely hasn't reached) - this problem occurs to me only in macOS (at least according to what I was not

I wonder if it's an expected approach to create multiple io_context to run in parallel or serially one right after the other ?

Here's my code :

```
std::string ExecuteProcess(const std::filesystem::path& processPath,
                           const std::vector<std::string>& args,
                           const std::chrono::seconds& time,
                           std::error_code& ec) {
  boost::asio::io_context ioc;
  std::future<std::string> data;
  std::future<std::string> err_output;
  boost::process::child child(
      boost::process::exe = process_path.string(),
      boost::process::args = arguments, boost::process::std_out > data,
      boost::process::std_err > err_output, ioc,
      boost::process::on_exit(
          [&ec, &ioc, error_code) {
            // do stuff with ec
            ioc.stop();
          }));

  ioc.run_for(time); // this should end when process complete or after timeout
  if (child.running()) {
    child.terminate();
  }

  if (data.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready) { // no need to wait here
    std::string output = data.get();
    return output;
  } else {
    ec = boost::asio::error::make_error_code(boost::asio::error::timed_out);
    return "";
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a lot of errors in the code, which tells us the code is not **not** your actual code.

From experience I can guess what the problem is.

Likely you are reusing the `io_context`. And the fact that you redundantly `ioc.stop()` when the child process exits (through normal or abnormal termination) tells me that you don't realize that `io_context.run()` will **always** return (stop) when it runs out of work.

When the service runs out of work it always return immediate from `run()` until `restart()` was called: [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html)

> *A normal exit from the `run()` function implies that the io_context object is stopped (the `stopped()` function returns true). Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately unless there is a prior call to `restart()`*

In your case I'd just not share the context, like your code here shows

There are some other intricacies. E.g. this is a race condition, really

```
if (child.running())
    child.terminate();
```

Better to just ignore the error from `terminate`.

If your child process should **not** receive `stdin`, better to also disconnect with `bp::std_in.null()`.

`make_error_code` should be invoked by ADL, so you get the behavior intended by the library designers:

```
    ec = make_error_code(asio::error::timed_out);
```

> In fact, instead of relying on the conversions provided by `boost::system::error_code` you might simply provide `is_error_code_enum` trait and [rely on constructor overload (3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/error_code) which does exactly what I just described:
>
> ```
>   ec = asio::error::timed_out;
> ```

Perhaps in similar vein, if you use `boost::filesystem::path` you'll benefit from direct support in `boost::process`, so you don't have to bottom out of the type system using `path::string`, `path::generic` or `path::native`. In fact I think `native()` would have been correct here.

If you accept a duration type you avoid unnecessary rounding to seconds.

It's likely advisable to wrap the child in a process group, so that you don't leave grandchildren around when you terminate the child.

Here's my take:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d90005e0ad6ed545)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using duration = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string ExecuteProcess(boost::filesystem::path  exe,
                           std::vector<std::string> args, //
                           duration                 time, //
                           std::error_code&         ec) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    asio::io_context         ioc;
    std::future<std::string> data, err_output;

    bp::group g;
    bp::child child(exe, args, ioc, g, bp::error(ec),
                    bp::std_in.null(),  //
                    bp::std_out > data, //
                    bp::std_err > err_output);

    ioc.run_for(time);
    if (std::error_code ignore; child.running())
        g.terminate(ignore);

    if (data.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready)
        return data.get();

    ec = make_error_code(asio::error::timed_out);
    return {};
}

int main() {
    constexpr duration timeout = 20ms;
    constexpr auto     script  = "sleep 0.0$RANDOM; echo -n 'Hello world'";

    for (std::error_code ec; /**/;) {
        auto s = ExecuteProcess("/usr/bin/bash", {"-c", script}, timeout, ec);

        std::cout << "got " << ec.message() << ": " << quoted(s) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
got Success: "Hello world"
got Success: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: ""
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: "Hello world"
got Connection timed out: ""
```