# Using single io_context to run mutlple processes with timeout

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

I've slightly changed the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037164/using-multiple-io-context-in-one-process-lead-to-timeout) to run all processes from a single io_context object which is defined in main, and delivered to each task, runs from a different thread.

I was expecting all tasks to complete successfully since they should take less than the timeout. However, I'm getting timeout on all the tasks. Any idea why ?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using duration = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string ExecuteProcess(boost::filesystem::path  exe,
                           std::vector<std::string> args, //
                           duration                 time, //
                           std::error_code&         ec, 
               asio::io_context&        ioc) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    std::future<std::string> data, err_output;

    bp::group g;
    bp::child child(exe, args, ioc, g, bp::error(ec),
                    bp::std_in.null(),  //
                    bp::std_out > data, //
                    bp::std_err > err_output);

    if (std::error_code ignore; child.running()) {
        g.terminate(ignore);
    }

    if (data.wait_for(time) == std::future_status::ready) {
        ec.clear();
        return data.get();
    }

    ec = make_error_code(asio::error::timed_out);
    return {};
}

int main() {
    constexpr duration timeout = 20ms;
    constexpr auto     script2  = "sleep 0.00005; echo -n 'Hello world'";
    constexpr auto     script1 = "/usr/bin/curl http://httpbin.org/ip -m 5";

    asio::io_context         ioc;
 
    boost::asio::detail::thread_group collect_threads;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
        collect_threads.create_thread([&]() {
            std::error_code ec_;
            auto s = ExecuteProcess("/bin/bash",    {"-c", script2}, timeout, ec_, ioc);
            std::cout << "got " << ec_.message() << ": " << s << std::endl;
        });
    }
    ioc.run();
}
```

P.S:
For the timeout implementation, I was also considering the option to use `result = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)` instead of `std::future`.
However, when I've finished waiting and the process stdout seems correct, the check `child.exit_code()` return 383 which means that the process still running - not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me forever to see, but... you actively terminate the child, before waiting for any result ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

With some re-ordering, and other minor tweaks:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecc1b35de7ffb7db)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using duration = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string ExecuteProcess(boost::filesystem::path  exe,
                           std::vector<std::string> args, //
                           duration                 time, //
                           std::error_code&         ec,   //
                           asio::io_context&        ioc) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    std::future<std::string> data, err_output;

    auto const deadline = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + time;

    bp::group  g;
    ec.clear();
    bp::child child(exe, args, ioc, g, bp::error(ec), bp::std_in.null(), bp::std_out > data,
                    bp::std_err > err_output);

    if (ec)
        return {};

    if (data.wait_until(deadline) == std::future_status::ready)
        return data.get();

    if (std::error_code ignore; child.running(ignore))
        g.terminate(ignore);

    ec = make_error_code(asio::error::timed_out); // TODO FIXME
    return {};
}

int main() {
    constexpr duration              timeout = 20ms;
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto script1 = "/usr/bin/curl http://httpbin.org/ip -m 5";
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto script2 = R"(delay="0.0$RANDOM"; sleep "$delay"; echo -n "sanity restored after $delay")";

    asio::io_context ioc;

    auto        work = make_work_guard(ioc); // prevent running out of work
    std::thread io_thread([&ioc] { ioc.run(); });

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::error_code ec;

        auto s = ExecuteProcess("/bin/bash", {"-c", script2}, timeout, ec, ioc);
        std::cout << "got " << ec.message() << ": " << quoted(s) << std::endl;
    }

    work.reset(); // allow running out of work
    io_thread.join();
}
```

Prints e.g.

[image]

Comment: Let's move the conversation here. :) The problem is that you are printing the `delay` environment variable inside the bash execution, but that's not what takes the most time; it's the creation of the child process. If you measure the ExecuteProcess() call, it's likely to come out around 2 seconds.

Comment: @bbalazs  I’m merely printing it as a secondary point of view. The process completes well within the 20 ms as observed from the C++ side as well, this is very obvious especially from the animated demo. You’re right that the output is irrelevant, but irrelevant output does not invalidate the other observations. Also it helps in confirming that delays > ~20ms are not getting through. as desired.

Comment: Sorry mate, seems I was tired yesterday and the live-run confused me a bit. Yes, you're right, OP terminated the child process immediately, that's why the future expired. You have my upvote.

Comment: Hi @sehe, I've found out that if I use the method wait_for/wait_until from std::future than it uses conditional_variable under the hood which doesn't yield. Perhaps you know if there's a substitution in boost that also yield ?

Comment: But... The entire interface is explicitly synchronous? I'm wondering what use it is to synchronously await the process/timeout of you're going to block on the future anyways. Of course this is all a fancy way to say it's not entirely trivial and I have to be behind a computer to give a better answer (which will merit its own question)

Answer (score 0):

Thread creation takes time, your `ioc.run()` is executed before the threads start using the `io_context`, therefore the `run()` returns immediately.

This is what you might want:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_context ctx;
boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> workGuard(ctx.get_executor());

ctx.run();
```

Call `workGuard.reset()` on other thread if you want the `io_context::run()` stop.

**Side note**: it's not advised to use anything from a namespace called `detail`. It's usually the playground of the given library, might be changed over time without any notice.

### Update

It's also necessary to increase the timeout. 20ms is way too short to execute a child process. It works perfectly with 2s.

Comment: unfortunately, even after I put sleep between the thread creation and the call to ioc.run, I see that data (from type std::future) never become std::future_status::ready. Perhaps you can modify my example with your suggestion so I can check it ?

Comment: @Zohar81 I've updated the answer to address this question too.

Comment: How did you test that, @bbalazs?

Comment: @sehe Added a 2s sleep before ioc.run() and changed the timeout to 2s.

Comment: I'm very surprised that appeared to work, since I've spent quite some time looking at why it didn't (of course I immediately tried your work-around as well). See my answer

Comment: I guess it might be different on, say, Windows

Comment: @sehe No, it's Arch linux. I've measured how much time the whole ExecuteProcess requires and it's around 2s. So using 2s, 2500ms as `timeout` is sufficient on my system.
Oddly 3-4 out of the 20 ExecuteProcess calls return empty string but 'Success' `ec_`, but I guess it's another problem.
Perhaps it's worth mentioning that I am referring to `constexpr duration timeout = 20ms;` as `timeout`.

Comment: Interesting. Can you follow the analysis in my answer? Interestingly there *is* a race before the termination. The only real way it could ever work is when the entire child process already completed before that point. My own outputs (both online on Coliru and also my animated demo) prove that 20ms is more than enough. I respect Arch enough that it shouldn't deviate that much. I'm quite sure there's an observer error at play somewhere.