# Using single io_context to run mutlple processes with timeout in parallel

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

I've tried to modify the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104005/using-single-io-context-to-run-mutlple-processes-with-timeout) and make the processes run in parallel since in my use case, the processes can be idle for a large portion of their lifecycle, so cpu resource can be better utilize when running in parallel

1. First I've tried that each task will run from boost::thread_group object.
   While running it, I got sometimes unexpected behavior that led to crash for the reasons below :

```
a.out(17512,0x1dac25c40) malloc: *** error for object 0x600003d60000: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(17512,0x1dac25c40) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

````
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::__1::future_error: The associated promise has been destructed prior to the associated state becoming ready.```
````

2. Then I've tried to replace the thread_group and run everything from the io_context using `boost::asio::post(ioc, [&]() {` but it didn't go well either since i got deadlock where the std::future is blocking the thread, and prevent the process from running. I guess it's possible to add more threads to run io_context, but i prefer to have some std::future that can yield.

I'd be happy to hear suggestions to repair my code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


using duration = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string ExecuteProcess(boost::filesystem::path  exe,
                           std::vector<std::string> args, //
                           duration                 time, //
                           std::error_code&         ec,   //
                           asio::io_context&        ioc) {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    std::future<std::string> data, err_output;

    auto const deadline = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + time;

    bp::group  g;
    ec.clear();
    bp::child child(exe, args, ioc, g, bp::error(ec), bp::std_in.null(), bp::std_out > data,
                    bp::std_err > err_output);

    if (ec) {
        return {};
    }

    if (data.wait_until(deadline) == std::future_status::ready) {
        return data.get();
    }

    if (std::error_code ignore; child.running(ignore)) {
        g.terminate(ignore);
    }

    ec = make_error_code(asio::error::timed_out); // TODO FIXME
    return {};
}

int main() {
    constexpr duration              timeout = 20s;
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto script1 = "/usr/bin/curl http://httpbin.org/ip -m 5";
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto script2 = R"(delay="0.5"; sleep "$delay"; echo -n "sanity restored after $delay")";

    asio::io_context ioc;

    auto        work = make_work_guard(ioc); // prevent running out of work
    std::thread io_thread([&ioc] { ioc.run(); });


// Option 1 : use thread group

//    boost::thread_group worker_threads;
//    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
//      worker_threads.create_thread([&]() {
//          std::error_code ec;
//          auto s = ExecuteProcess("/bin/bash", {"-c", script2}, timeout, ec, ioc);
//          std::cout << "got " << ec.message() << ": " << s << std::endl;
//      });
//    }
//
//    work.reset(); // allow running out of work
//    io_thread.join();
//    worker_threads.join_all();



// Option 2 : use post-io_context
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    boost::asio::post(ioc, [&]() {
            std::error_code ec;
            auto s = ExecuteProcess("/bin/bash", {"-c", script2}, timeout, ec, ioc);
            std::cout << "got " << ec.message() << ": " << s << std::endl;
      });
    }
    work.reset(); // allow running out of work
    io_thread.join();

}
```

the code can be compiled for testing using the following command :

```
g++ -std=c++20 -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -lboost_{thread,coroutine,context} ~/main.cpp -I<path_to_boost_headers> -L<path_to_boost_libs>
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to make asynchronous? None of the approaches you show are actually asynchronous. They're just synchronous running on multiple threads. I can imagine some useful interfaces, but (a) they [exist](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost/process/async_system.html) to a degree (b) they might not fit your expectations/requirements so I would like to be sure before I spend a lot of time building imagenary solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I should rephrase 'asynchronous' and use 'parallel' instead.. The goal is that all sub-processes will run in parallel which is much more effective in my case, and the output data will be printed/collected when each processes finish running.

Comment: There's a big difference between "printed" and "collected". Which is the actual requirement? (Note that processes already naturally run in parallel: they're threads in a different process space)

Comment: I think I understand your point, since if we print output of processes which are running in parallel, the result can be mixed/interleaved... For my use case, I collect the output of each processes and store it in separate file so there won't be any mixing.

Comment: Mmm. Sounds like you could directly have the subprocess write to the file, and basically don't mind when the processes finish. I guess the whole thing then boils down to "limiting the time per subprocess". In that case, I strongly suggest using some existing tool like [coreutils `timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation), so you can simply say `timeout 15 bash -c etc`. But I know enough to sketch an answer nonetheless in case you want to have it C++ side

Comment: Yes I prefer full c++ solution since I want to do it cross platform and not all platforms provide coreutils.timeout, also i want to understand what is bad with my current solution and maybe how to fix it if it's not totally flawed

Comment: I'll be back later and answer these. Got to go for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. It's a bit annoying that `boost::process::child` doesn't expose a regular async interface compatible with completion tokens, despite the fact that it tightly integrates with Asio and naturally deals with 100% asynchronous *processes*.

This interface **does** exist: https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost/process/async_system.html. However, it cannot work with c++14-only completion tokens. Also it has the very old anti-pattern of passing a reference to `asio::io_context` around.

This makes it hard to intelligently use it e.g. with a strand or even with `asio::thread_pool`. However, we can roll our own initiation function that gets around those downsides. Sadly, we will always need an `io_context` instance, though you might choose to use an internal ("global") instance hidden from the interface.

With some convenience typedefs

```
using boost::filesystem::path;
using Signature = void(std::error_code, int, std::string);
using Duration  = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
using Args      = std::vector<std::string>;
```

Let's define our [completion token](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) interface as

```
template <typename Token>
auto asyncExecuteProcess(                                       //
    path exe, Args args, Duration limit, asio::io_context& ioc, //
    Token&& token);
```

Before we dive in deep, this is how we expect to use it to run many processes in parallel under some time constraints and handle each result as soon as it is ready:

```cpp
int main() {
    using ProcessExecution::asyncExecuteProcess;

    constexpr auto timeout = 50ms;
    constexpr auto script  = R"(
         number=$((1 + $RANDOM % 9));
         sleep "0.0$number";
         echo -n "sanity restored after 0.0$number";
         exit $number
    )";

    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        asyncExecuteProcess(                           //
            "/bin/bash", {"-c", script}, timeout, ioc, //
            [i](std::error_code ec, int exit_code, std::string data) {
                if (ec)
                    std::cout << "Completed #" << i << " " << ec.message() << " " << exit_code << " "
                              << quoted(data) << std::endl;
            });

    std::cout << "Everything initiated, single-threaded multiplexed completion" << std::endl;

    work.reset();
    ioc.run();
}
```

The embedded bash script sleeps randomly between 1..10 * 10ms, and returns the corresponding exit code 1..10. Since we start them all "immediately", we expect the results to come in ascending order of delay, but not necessarily in order of job number (#i).

Since all delays > 50ms should timeout, we expect the few last entries to show errors.

### The Magic

In the implementation details we need to deduce an associated executor (in case the completion token is e.g. `bind_executor(my_strand, asio::use_awaitable)`).

```
auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(token, ioc.get_executor());
```

Next up, some resources need to be allocated so they remain stable for the duration of our async operation:

```
auto a  = asio::get_associated_allocator(token);
auto st = std::allocate_shared<stable_state>(a, ex, deadline);
```

Stable state contains all the things that cannot be (cheaply) moved:

```
struct stable_state : std::enable_shared_from_this<stable_state> {
    stable_state(asio::any_io_executor ex, time_point t) : timer(ex, t) {}
    asio::steady_timer       timer;
    bp::group                process_group;
    std::future<std::string> out, err;

    void arm_timer() {
        timer.async_wait([self = this /*->shared_from_this()*/](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec)
                self->process_group.terminate(ec);
        });
    }
};
```

The remaining bits of the initiation function may look like this:

```
auto init = [&ioc, ex, st] //
    (auto&& handler, path exe, Args args) {
        auto wrapped_handler = [h = std::move(handler), ex, st] //
            (int exit_code, std::error_code ec) mutable {
                bool terminated = !st->timer.expires_at(time_point::min());
                bool ok         = !terminated && !ec;

                std::string data;
                if (ok) {
                    if (st->out.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready)
                        data = st->out.get();
                    else
                        ec = make_error_code(asio::error::interrupted); // TODO
                }

                if (terminated) {
                    data = "Killed";
                    if (!ec)
                        ec = make_error_code(asio::error::operation_aborted);
                }

                assert(st.unique());
                st.reset(); // deallocate before invoking the handler

                asio::dispatch(                                                //
                    ex, [=, h = std::move(h), d = std::move(data)]() mutable { //
                        std::move(h)(ec, exit_code, std::move(d));
                    });
            };

        bp::child(ioc, exe, args,        //
                  st->process_group,     //
                  bp::std_in.null(),     //
                  bp::std_out > st->out, //
                  bp::std_err > st->err, //
                  bp::on_exit(std::move(wrapped_handler)))
            .detach();

        st->arm_timer();
    };
return asio::async_initiate<Token, Signature>( //
    init, token, std::move(exe), std::move(args));
```

> Note I elected to "soft-detect" termination indirectly by detecting whether the timer had already completed. On POSIX, a much nicer way to do it would be keeping `bp::child` in the stable-state and querying the `native_exit_code` like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733210/85371

Most of the code otherwise is making sure that the right executor is used¹, the allocations are freed at the required moments and doing various asserts to guard against programming mistakes.

### DEMO TIME

Of course, where would we be without proof of the pudding:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60f93c3fe7db1346)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

namespace ProcessExecution {
    using boost::filesystem::path;
    using Signature = void(std::error_code, int, std::string);
    using Duration  = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;
    using Args      = std::vector<std::string>;

    template <typename Token>
    auto asyncExecuteProcess(                                       //
        path exe, Args args, Duration limit, asio::io_context& ioc, //
        Token&& token)                                              //
    {
        namespace bp = boost::process;

        using time_point    = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;
        time_point deadline = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + limit;

        struct stable_state : std::enable_shared_from_this<stable_state> {
            stable_state(asio::any_io_executor ex, time_point t) : timer(ex, t) {}
            asio::steady_timer       timer;
            bp::group                process_group;
            std::future<std::string> out, err;

            void arm_timer() {
                timer.async_wait([self = this /*->shared_from_this()*/](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                    if (!ec)
                        self->process_group.terminate(ec);
                });
            }
        };

        auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(token, ioc.get_executor());
        auto a  = asio::get_associated_allocator(token);
        auto st = std::allocate_shared<stable_state>(a, ex, deadline);

        auto init = [&ioc, ex, st] //
            (auto&& handler, path exe, Args args) {
                auto wrapped_handler = [h = std::move(handler), ex, st] //
                    (int exit_code, std::error_code ec) mutable {
                        bool terminated = !st->timer.expires_at(time_point::min());
                        bool ok         = !terminated && !ec;

                        std::string data;
                        if (ok) {
                            if (st->out.wait_for(0s) == std::future_status::ready)
                                data = st->out.get();
                            else
                                ec = make_error_code(asio::error::interrupted); // TODO
                        }

                        if (terminated) {
                            data = "Killed";
                            if (!ec)
                                ec = make_error_code(asio::error::operation_aborted);
                        }

                        assert(st.unique());
                        st.reset(); // deallocate before invoking the handler

                        asio::dispatch(                                                //
                            ex, [=, h = std::move(h), d = std::move(data)]() mutable { //
                                std::move(h)(ec, exit_code, std::move(d));
                            });
                    };

                bp::child(ioc, exe, args,        //
                          st->process_group,     //
                          bp::std_in.null(),     //
                          bp::std_out > st->out, //
                          bp::std_err > st->err, //
                          bp::on_exit(std::move(wrapped_handler)))
                    .detach();

                st->arm_timer();
            };
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, Signature>( //
            init, token, std::move(exe), std::move(args));
    }
} // namespace ProcessExecution

int main() {
    using ProcessExecution::asyncExecuteProcess;

    constexpr auto timeout = 50ms;
    constexpr auto script  = R"(
         number=$((1 + $RANDOM % 9));
         sleep "0.0$number";
         echo -n "sanity restored after 0.0$number";
         exit $number
    )";

    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    auto work = make_work_guard(ioc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        asyncExecuteProcess(                           //
            "/bin/bash", {"-c", script}, timeout, ioc, //
            [i](std::error_code ec, int exit_code, std::string data) {
                std::cout << "Completed #" << i << " " << ec.message() << " " << exit_code << " "
                          << quoted(data) << std::endl;
            });

    std::cout << "Everything initiated, single-threaded multiplexed completion" << std::endl;

    work.reset();
    ioc.run();
}
```

[image]

---

¹ there's a subtle race still here, where even if `terminated==false` we still have to check that the `out` future is `ready`. If we don't, we can get very unlucky and have a race where the future is never ready but the process has been killed. I suspect this is indicating that Boost Process actually doesn't perform all the work on an service thread (as required). I'll probably look into this later.

Comment: And of course, now my eye falls on a V2 interface in Boost Process. It's unclear to me what the development status is, but this interface looks a lot more promising https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_process/v2.html#boost_process.v2.quickstart.execute